# selecting multiple values in reactive form angular not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I m trying to be able to use multiple selection in Angular reactive forum but getting error "Value must be an array in multiple-selection mode".
Tried to change the type of "config.name" to string array but nothing changed.
Any ideas what am i doing wrong ?

```
 <mat-form-field [formGroup]="group" [ngStyle]="config.styles">
      <mat-label>{{ config.label }}</mat-label>
      <mat-select multiple [formControlName]="config.name" [placeholder]="config.placeholder">
        <mat-option [value]="option.value" (click)="logIt(option.value)" *ngFor="let option of config.options">
          {{ option.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of config.validation" ngProjectAs="mat-error">
          <mat-error *ngIf="group.controls[config['name']].hasError(validation.name)">{{validation.message}}</mat-error>
        </ng-container>
    </mat-form-field>


export interface IConfig {
  disabled?: boolean;
  label?: string;
  name: string;
  options?: object[];
  placeholder?: string;
  type: string;
  validation?: Validator[];
  value?: any;
}
```

Comment: What does config look like?

Comment: IConfig is the interface of the config there

Comment: @TolgaTamer can you add example of IConfig and form?

Comment: Are you trying to preselect the values using `setValue(...)` or `patchValue(...)`? The corresponding values for `config.name` should be an array.

Comment: If ‘config.name’ is a string, it’s incorrectly typed. This should be of type formControl.

Comment: how can i fix below getting same issues ??